# What test(s) for my data?

Tags: time-series, group-differences

I'm trying to analyse data for my psych undergrad dissertation but struggling with which tests to use because my project is unlike anything I've had experience with previously (and also I don't have a mind for statistics). I have 200 cases of patients who've attended therapy, and the dates of every session they attended. I made extra variables for the number of days wait between each session but I want to know whether different diagnoses (e.g. depression, anxiety...) had an effect on how often patients came for therapy. The trouble is that the diagnostic groups have very different n in each (there are 5 main diagnostic groups, ranging from n = 109 to n = 3!). I'm not sure if there's anyway to do this?

Any advice much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking about differences in *rates* (# per unit time), differences in *counts* (total # of visits), or differences in the *durations* (amount of time passed until they were done w/ therapy)? Note also, that you probably didn't randomly assign the patients to differing diagnoses, so you can't infer the "effect" of the diagnosis, only that it is *associated* w/ differing responses.